# Alchemy plugin only waits for 30 sec to get the response from .net service

Tags: sdl-tridion, a4t

I have created an alchemy plugin which synchronizes the components based on schema.
If the service take more than 30 sec to sync all the components then we will not get any response
and gets this error message in console of the brower:

> Dashboard_v8.5.0.22656.404_.aspx?mode=js:1594 Uncaught TypeError:
>   Cannot read property 'message' of undefined
>       at XMLHttpRequest.eval (Dashboard_v8.5.0.22656.404_.aspx?mode=js:1594)

**My jscode:**

```
execute: function(selection) {
if (purpose == "Component" || purpose == "Schema") {
    var progress = $messages.registerProgress("Syncing Items...", null);
    Alchemy.Plugins["${PluginName}"].Api.ComponentSyncService.getSynchronized({
            tcm: selection.getItem(0),
            flag: "ALL"
        })
        .success(function(synchronized) {
            console.log("synchronized", synchronized);
            var ResponseObj = JSON.parse(synchronized);
            if (ResponseObj.Warning != null && ResponseObj.Warning != '') {
                $messages.registerWarning(ResponseObj.TimeTaken + " " + ResponseObj.Warning);
            } else if (ResponseObj.Success != null && ResponseObj.Success != '') {
                $messages.registerGoal(ResponseObj.TimeTaken + " " + ResponseObj.Success);
            } else if (ResponseObj.Error != null && ResponseObj.Error != '') {
                $messages.registerError(ResponseObj.TimeTaken + " " + ResponseObj.Error);
            }
        })
        .error(function(type, error) {
            $messages.registerError("There was an error in item Synchronization", error.message);
        })
        .complete(function() {
            progress.finish();
        });
} else {
    $messages.registerProgress("Incorrect selection. Supported Type: ( Component, page, keyword and structure group ) Schema and Components only", null);
}
```

}

Comment: What timeouts have you explored in your Tridion configuration files?

Comment: @Dylan..MarkSaunders how can we locate the tridion configuration file in the server as there are many .config files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found out that there is file inside Alchmey folder qwest.js where default values are set :
options.timeout = 'timeout' in options?parseInt (options.timeout,10):30000;